# Finding zeroes of a modified Bessel function of the second kind

Tags: equation-solving

Let
$$
f_n(\omega):=K_{i \omega}(2\pi n)
$$
with $\omega>0$, $n=1,2,\ldots$ and $K_{\nu}$ a modified Bessel function of the second kind.

For each fixed value of $n$, $f_n(\omega)$ has an infinite number of zeros $\omega_{n\,k}>0$, labeled by an integer $k$, that is to say $f_n(\omega_{n\,k})=0$.

These zeros can then the ordered, and I would like to accurately determine the first 1500. I tried using the Ted Ersek's `rootSearch`, but it gets very sluggish even for moderate values of $n$ such as $n=20$. These zeros are likely to fall in the range $0<\omega<250$ and have $1\leq n\leq 35$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the fast decay of the absolute value as shown by

```
  f[n_,ω_] := BesselK[I ω, 2 π n]

  Plot[E^(6 + (ω^1.09)) f[ 2, ω], {ω, 6, 125}]
```

[image: Plot of Bessel K over the index]

The exponent of $\omega$ in the exponential scaling is
very critical. But in general, in order to [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) consecutive zeros its crucial to scale the function to a slowly varying amplitude.